# How do I design around this circular dependency issue?

Tags: node.js, dns, dependencies, circular-dependency

I have a class Domain.

I have a class SubDomain.

A SubDomain is a Domain.

A Domain should have a method to create a new SubDomain.

How is this designed to avoid circular dependency? A Domain seem to have to depend on SubDomain in order to be able to create a new SubDomain. Or am I missing something?.

Comment: A SubDomain **IS** a Domain as the DNS tree is recursive, and each node is exactly the same thing, it may just differ in its parent, and children. You shouldn't have two classes for that. But further than that, your model depends on constraints you don't list so it is difficult to help you and your question at this stage might be more on topic on softwareengineering than here, since you don't show any code or details on the problem space.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I guess this was intended as more of a general softwareengineering question yes. I'm still trying to figure out for myself why, if for any reason I can't just use one Domain class. I suppose my uncomfort comes partly from a beleif that a Domain should be standalone whereas a SubDomain should be passed a parent Domain for reference.